# In my blog template I am getting Hugh empty space between blogger post and blogger footer

Tags: html, css, xml, blogger, blogger-dynamic-views

in my external blogger template empty space between blogger post and footer. how can i reduce that space?

blog link below
http://chalaudyojakghadwuya.blogspot.in/

Answer (score 0):

remove visibility : hidden; of #sidebar-wrapper, and replace it by display : none;